# Echoing the domain I'm 301 redirecting in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5.3

I'm redirecting a secondary domain in my routes:

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'http://olddomain.com'], function() {
    Route::get('/', function() {       
        return Redirect::to('http://newdomain.com/', 301);       
    });
});
```

I want to be able to add an alert to a page that was redirected from olddomain.com. My solution is to use an if statement but I don't know how to check if the user has entered olddomain.com if there's a redirect happening.

Is there any way to echo olddomain.com if that's how the user is trying to access the site?

Comment: You dont have guarranted information from the user's referer. You'll have to pass that info in your URL as parameter and detect it at your new domain controller. Check my answer for the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to flash it to a session?  Once you detect the first request, you should be able to add some information to the session.  Once you redirect, you can check to see if this information exists in the session, and if it does, perform whatever action you need.

To start, you should always point your routes to an actual controller.  It doesn't take much work, and later on it will allow you to take advantage of Laravel's route caching.  Assuming you are using a Controller, your code might look like this.

```
public function oldRoute(){
    Session::flash('old_route', \Request::url());
    // Perform any additional logic
    return Redirect::to('http://newdomain.com/', 301);
}

public function newRoute(){
    if(!empty(Session::get('old_route'){
        // You know the user came from the old route
    }

    // Return your view
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need to do $request->session()->flash('old_route', \Request::url())?

Comment: You should be able to do both.  In the most recent documentation Taylor does use $request->session(), so it's probably best practice to start doing it that way.  In my example I simply used the Session Facade.  This will give you access to the public methods within Illuminate\Session\Store.php

Comment: Ok. So I did this in my controller:

     session()->flash('forwardHome', \Request::url());
     return redirect('http://newdomain.com', 301);

And then I did this in my view:

 if(!empty(session()->flash('forwardHome')))
 {
  echo 'forward';
 }

But I get this:

Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Session\Store::flash()

Comment: I apologise, I had an error in my code.  I've made an edit that should work for you.  Basically, you only flash data into the session, when you want to retriieve the data you still say session()->get('forwardHome').

Comment: Thank you. The missing argument error is gone. But when I go to the old route and redirected, the code that's in the if statement isn't executed.

Comment: Session data do not persist cross origin domains. Right after you redirect to a new domain, your session is discarded and a new one is created. That's why the if statement fails.

Answer (score 0):

Because session data are not preserved accross different domains, the simplier approach would be to pass a hashed parameter into your url before you redirect to the new domain.

On your new domain you can detect the url parameter, decrypt it and do your stuff accordingly.

**Routes redirect cross-domain with hashed token parameter**

```
// Your secret key can be anything you want
$secretKey = 'oldlaravel.dev';

Route::group(['domain' => 'oldlaravel.dev'], function() use ($secretKey) {
    Route::get('/', function() use ($secretKey) {

        $hashedToken = Hash::make($secretKey);
        return Redirect::to("http://newlaravel.dev?token=$hashedToken", 301);

    });
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'newlaravel.dev'], function() use ($secretKey) {
    Route::get('/', function() use ($secretKey) {

        if (Request::get('token')) {
            if (Hash::check($secretKey, Request::get('token'))) {
                echo 'You got here by redirect from my old domain!';
            } else {
                echo 'Who the hell are you?!'; //came here with an invalid token parameter
            }
        } else {
            echo 'You got here directly!';
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem as with the solution below. The code that's supposed to be executed if redirect is present is not executed.

Comment: When I print_r the session data, I don't get the redirect variable. It says [_flash] => Array.

Comment: You were right. I've updated my answer with a new approach!